# Using PointCloud Prefab on Unity 3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-project-tango

I tryed to implement the "Measure It" app on Unity 3D. I started with the PointCloud example scene downloaded on tango's website.

My problem is, when i look in 1st Person view, the point cloud don't fiel the screen, and when i look in 3rd Person I can see the point outside the Unity Camera FOV.

I don't see this problem on the Explorer app, but it looks to be made in Java so I think it's a Unity compatibility problem.

Does someone have the same problem, or a solution?

Unity 3D 5.1.1
Google Tango urquhart

Sorry for my poor english,

Regards.

EDIT :

It looks like the ExperimentalAugmentedReality scene is using the point cloud to place markers in real world, and this point cloud is right in front of the camera. I don't see any script difference between them so i don't understand why it works. If you've any idea.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? We have the exact same problem...

Answer (score 0):

I think it makes sense to divide you question into two parts.

1. Why the points are not filling in the screen in the point cloud example.

In order to make the points to fill in the first person view camera, the render camera's FOV needs to match the physical depth camera's FOV. In the point cloud example, I believe Tango is just using the default Unity camera's FOV, that's why you saw the points is not filling the screen(render camera).

In the third person camera view, the frustum is just a visual representation of the device movement. It doesn't indicate the FOV or any camera intrinsics of the device. For the visualization purpose, Tango explore might specifically matched the camera frustum size to the actual camera FOV, but that's not guaranteed to be 100% accurate.

2. Why the AR example works.

In the AR example, we must set the virtual render camera's FOV to match the physical camera's FOV, otherwise the AR view will be off. On the Tango hardware, the color camera and depth camera are the same camera sensor, so they shared a same FOV. That's why the AR example works.